# Node-soap - add a header with multiple namespaces

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I'm using `node-soap` to communicate with a service that expects a header with elements in different namespaces.

Using a tool like `SoapUI` the header should look like this:

````
```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tcorHeaders="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreHeaders.xsd" xmlns:tcorTypes="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tcorHeaders:sessionHeader>
         <tcorHeaders:sessionToken>
            <tcorTypes:primary>token1</tcorTypes:primary>
            <tcorTypes:secondary>token2</tcorTypes:secondary>
            <tcorTypes:expiration>2018-09-19T03:35:19.478Z</tcorTypes:expiration>
         </tcorHeaders:sessionToken>
      </tcorHeaders:sessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
```
````

But if I do:

```
client.addSoapHeader({
  sessionHeader : { 
    sessionToken: {
        primary : 'token1', 
        secondary: 'token2', 
        expiration : '2018-09-19T03:35:19.478Z' }}, 
'', 'types', 'http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd');
```

Then the output will look like this:

````
```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:headers="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreHeaders.xsd" xmlns:types="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <types:sessionHeader xmlns:types="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd" xmlns="http://www.tcore.com/TcoreTypes.xsd">
            <types:sessionToken>
                <types:primary>token1</types:primary>
                <types:secondary>token2</types:secondary>
                <types:expiration>2018-09-19T03:35:19.478Z</types:expiration>
            </types:sessionToken>
        </types:sessionHeader>
    </soap:Header>
```
````

With everything assigned to `types` and nothing assigned to `headers`.

How can I set a header containing an object with 2 different namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I found an inelegant solution from the [docs](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#overriding-the-namespace-prefix)

Using the override I manually created the header object like this:

```
dclient.addSoapHeader({ 'headers:sessionHeader': 
    { 'headers:sessionToken': 
        { 'types:primary': token.primary, 
          'types:secondary': token.secondary, 
          'types:expiration': token.expiration } } });
```

This works because `node-soap` is consistent with it's naming conventions, but you will have to run a dummy request and then view the sent xml (`result[3]` if debugging)